# More efficient way to get the intersection between 2 or more nested ArrayLists

Tags: java, list, arraylist, set-intersection

If I had, say separate 3 nested `ArrayLists` of Strings, i.e., `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`:

1. What is the most efficient way of finding their intersection (common elements)?
2. Are there other data structures to replace the nested `ArrayLists` structure that could improve the efficiency of finding their intersection? (e.g. The first structure I can think of is using a `Set`, but I would like to see if there are other suggestions for this.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yep, you want a set. Any kind of set will do. `HashSet` will probably be faster in general, whereas `TreeSet` will behave more predictably and may be faster at small sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of two lists is done using the `retainAll()` method.

It update the list, so if you don't want that, you should copy the list first.

If you have more than 2 lists, you copy the first and then call `retainAll()` for each of the remaining lists.

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists = ...

List<String> intersection = new ArrayList<>(lists.get(0));
for (List<String> list : lists.subList(1, lists.size()))
    intersection.retainAll(list);
```

However performance will be a bad *O(n*m)*, where `n` and `m` are the sizes of the two largest lists.

That is because `retainAll()` does a `contains()` against the list given in the parameter, which is a sequential search, for each element in the `intersection` list.

Performance can be improved to *O(n)*, where `n` is the largest list, by converting the lists to sets.

```java
List<String> intersection = new ArrayList<>(lists.get(0));
for (List<String> list : lists.subList(1, lists.size()))
    intersection.retainAll(new HashSet<>(list));
```

In Java 8+, the `for` loop can be simplified to one of these:

```java
lists.subList(1, lists.size()).stream().map(HashSet::new).forEach(intersection::retainAll);

lists.subList(1, lists.size()).forEach(list -> intersection.retainAll(new HashSet<>(list)));
```

Answer (score 1):

i would use the [list.retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) method as in

```
private ArrayList<String> getIntersection(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists) {
    if(null == lists || lists.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    ArrayList<String> intersection = lists.get(0);
    lists.forEach(intersection::retainAll);
    return intersection;
}
```